# wxPython RichTextCtrl.SetStyle([...]) Issue

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to change the font of a RichTextControl in wxPython but I've encountered an issue that I can not figure out. Here is the relevant code:

```
import wx
import wx.richtext as rt
#....
codebox = rt.RichTextCtrl(self)
f = wx.Font(10, wx.TELETYPE, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
s = wx.TextAttr(font = f)
codebox.SetStyle((0,0), s)
```

The last line is what throws an error. Specifically:

```
TypeError: in method 'RichTextCtrl_GetStyle', 
expected argument 3 of type 'wxTextAttrEx &'
```

I based my code on stuff I found online, however I immediately recognized that my version of wxPython was different because the tuple I supplied as a range in SetStyle() was instead supplied as two different arguments, however when I imitated that setup the interpreter threw me an error and asked me to use a tuple.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? Or, of course, a workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

s should be of type wx.TextAttrEx, not wx.TextAttr like you have done.

> SetStyle(self, range, style)
>
> Set the style for the text in range to style
>
> ```
> Parameters:
>     range
>                (type=RichTextRange)
>
>     style
>                (type=TextAttrEx)
> ```

Comment: I had noticed this before but reached a dead end because wx.TextAttrEx does not exist (as opposed to wx.TextAttr). But on further investigation, the type is under wx.richtext.TextAttrEx. Thanks Sticky!